# Pystan 2.19.1.1- C++/MSVC compiler issues- cl.exe failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, visual-c++, cl, pystan

Happy Halloween Weekend! Sorry that I have to reach out to ask for your expertise and your guidance regarding this issue I am facing with installing pystan and the C++ configuration. I have followed every single step in this website:https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html and I am still not sure what steps I am missing. this is the error that I am seeing:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py in compile(self, sources, output_dir, macros, include_dirs, debug, extra_preargs, extra_postargs, depends)
    424                 self.spawn(args)
    425             except DistutilsExecError as msg:
--> 426                 raise CompileError(msg)
    427 
    428         return objects

CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I just want to show here all the steps that I have taken and installed and honestly, I am not sure what steps that I am missing. Does this occur because of windows 11? or if any of the experts could help me understand what are the C++ configuration and requirement? I am trying my best to leave no stone unturned because I truly want to learn pystan.

Thank you for reading my post and helping with this.

1.Create pystan in conda environment: [![enter image description here]
Requirement already satisfied: pystan in c:\users\lanng\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.19.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython!=0.25.1,>=0.22 in c:\users\lanng\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pystan) (0.29.15)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in c:\users\lanng\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pystan) (1.18.1)

2.mingw-w64 installation checked
c++ (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I have followed all the installation guidance in this website: https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html
I really hope to understand why this issue occurred